# How to replace all text on my website to a predefined text using java script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all given text available over my website using java script. 
Here is my script

```
javascript:(function(){
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';

var theta = new RegExp(/(\S*\S)/gmi);
document.normalize();
var m = document.body.innerHTML;
var tri = document.body.innerText;
var quad = document.body.childNodes;
var mar = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
console.log(mar.length);

for(var i=0;i<quad.length;i++)
{   
    alert("LENGTH OF BODY "+quad.length);
if(quad[i].nodeName!="#comment" && quad[i].nodeName!="#text" && quad[i].nodeName!="SCRIPT"&& quad[i].nodeName!="IMG" && quad[i].nodeName!="HEADER")
 {  
    alert(quad[i].nodeName);
    getChildren(quad[i]);
 }  

}

function getChildren(quad)
    {
                for(var ti=0;ti<quad.length;ti++)
        {
            if(hasChildren(quad[ti]))
           {
            getChildren(quad[ti]);
           }

           else
           {

                  if(quad.data)
               {


                var mor = (quad.data).toString();
                   if(mor.match(theta))
                  {   
                    mor = mor.replace(/(\(\)\")/g,"");
                    mor=mor.replace("'",'"');
                    mor=mor.replace("&nbsp;",'');
                    mor = mor.trim();
                    if(document.body.innerText.indexOf(mor.toString())!=-1)
                    {
                        console.log("'"+mor+"'");
                        quad.nodeValue = " Hello ";
                    }
                  }
                }

           }

        }
        alert('done2343');

    }



function hasChildren(quad)
    {
    if(quad.length!=0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }

})();
```

I am  running this script in browser. I am trying to navigate each and every child node  and put String "Hello" into that but this script is not working. Can some one guide me.

Comment: You just want to iterate through all elements that aren't a control (ie - `<p>, <a>, <div>`, etc? And add "Hello" to them?

Comment: @RobScott Scott u mean to say its not possible?

Comment: No, I was asking if that's what you wanted - add "Hello" to every elements that's not a control (or an `img`)

Comment: @RobScott No Rob, I wanted to translate website in different local languages .so using java script i will grab all the text then replace them with translated string.  I am able to grab string but it included image, scripts , other stuff also. can u help me to remove that.In answer i have copied my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I googled it and found this solution is working for me

```
javascript:(function(){


function recurse(element)
{
    if (element.childNodes.length > 0) 
        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) 
            recurse(element.childNodes[i]);

    if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(element.nodeValue)) 
        {
            console.log(element);
            element.nodeValue="hello";

          }
}
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
recurse(html);
}

)();
```

but it include link, script , other stuff also . Is there any way to remove them ?